# How do I show Console.log based on state?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have pulled in two different states. And then for each state I have created a function, each printing a different console message. At the minute what I can do is, after I instantiate my class, I can call either method or both to print their console message manually. But How do I go about printing either console message based on the state being either 'ready' or 'saveSuccess'? My code is below.

```
'use strict';

class AnnServicePlugin {
  constructor(learnosity) {
    this._learnosity = learnosity;

    this._learnosity.on('ready', () => this._learnosityReady());
    this._learnosity.on('saveSuccess', () => this._learnositySuccess());
  }

  _learnosityReady() {
    console.log('Plugin Ready')
  }

  _learnositySuccess() {
    console.log('Plugin Success');
  } 
}

let annServicePlugin = new AnnServicePlugin(learnosity);
annServicePlugin._learnosityReady();

module.exports = AnnServicePlugin;
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this not work?

```
'use strict';

class AnnServicePlugin {
  constructor(learnosity) {
    this._learnosity = learnosity;

    this._learnosity.on('ready', () => this._learnosityReady());
    this._learnosity.on('saveSuccess', () => this._learnositySuccess());
  }

  _learnosityReady() {
    this._state = 'ready'
  }

  _learnositySuccess() {
    this._state = 'success'
  } 

  _learnosityPrint() {
    if (this._state == 'ready') {
       console.log('Plugin Ready')
    } else if (this._state == 'success') {
       console.log('Plugin Success')
    }
  }
}

let annServicePlugin = new AnnServicePlugin(learnosity);
annServicePlugin._learnosityPrint();

    module.exports = AnnServicePlugin;
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it worked for you? Thanks!